# Is there a way to access the files in my phone which is connected to PC through python?

Tags: python, android, operating-system

I want to filter 'my music' folder present in my mobile(Manufacturer: Realme, Os:Oreo ) through python.

```
import os
os.chdir(r'E:')   # I am able to change between C and E drive.
os.chdir(r'This PC\realme 3 Pro\Internal shared storage')  #throwing below error.
```

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:

I heard about that latest phones support MTP and PTP prtocols to transfer but not UMS.

Can anyone guide me how to get list of files that are present in the phone which is connected to PC.

Answer (score -1):

"This PC" is not a valid path. A Windows path should always start with one letter (ex: C:\, D:\, E:\, etc).
So if your phone is mounted to the E drive you should access it like this:

```
os.chdir(r'E:\realm 3 Pro\...')
```

Comment: My phone is not mounted as any drive. It is just mounted as realme 3 pro. I tried the path removing 'This pc' also. No use of that too.